# Can't find server serial number

Tags: bios, windows-server-2003, serial, cmd.exe

I am trying to find the serial number of a windows server 2003 R2.

I used a lot of tools but i couldn't find the serial number.

Note that i want the serial number and not the product key.

I also used the following command on cmd:

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

but the result is

```
serial number
```

and then empty lines, which is unexpected from my experience.
How can i find the serial number? What is wrong?

Comment: The serial number might not actually be stored in a machine readable format. While the functionality is often provided many systems end up with empty fields or with `insert serial number here` in the field rather than an actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not always set, and there are a few different places it can be set.  You could also use the hard disk serial # or the MAC address to help identify your machine.

A tool like [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) will display all these and more.

Comment: Belarc Advisor is the only program I have found that is able to display the actual serial number of Windows and other programs.  Other programs I have tested have not displayed the actual serial, despite their claim otherwise, the numbers they do display were actually invalid.